# Dot product and divergence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, vectors, vector-fields

Divergence is represented by dot product. How is the divergence related to dot product? And curl is represented by cross product. How is the curl related to cross product?

Comment: $\operatorname{div} F = \nabla  \cdot F$
,
$\operatorname{curl} F = \nabla  \times F$

Comment: Its just the dot/cross product of the Del operator with the vector

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a physics question and I consider it of too low quality to migrate it.

Comment: Thinking about the meaning of these notations (and that for the gradient) will start you on the road to understanding the algebra of differential operators.

Comment: it is related to physics...without this knowledge how 1 can understand the maxwell`s equations @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty much simply a short way to notate both vector field operations by looking at $\nabla$ as a vector operator by writing
\begin{equation}
\nabla=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
\end{equation}
in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or equivalently
\begin{equation}
\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{\imath}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat{\jmath}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat{k}.
\end{equation}
Performing this vector operator on a scalar field gives you the expression for that field's gradient, whereas applying it to a vector field via a dot product gives you the vector field's divergence (analogoulsy for the cross product, which gives you the field's curl instead).

It is important to note, however, that unlike with regular three-vectors, this expression for divergence is not commutative, as the $\nabla$ operator is not a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: i know that the dot product represents the divergence, but why the dot product represents the divergence?